# selecting specific lines using awk

Tags: awk

I have a file with lines like these

```
1 1000034 G C 0.4 12
2 1000435 C G 0.1 52
3 0092943 A T 0.2 5
4 0092241 G A 0.3 34
etc.
```

columns 3 and 4 only contain the characters AGCT

I need to print lines that DO NOT contain both G and C in columns 3 and 4.
What I´m trying so far in awk is doing

```
awk ' { if ($3!="G" && $4!="C") print }' file
```

but this is also excluding lines with G and A in columns 3 and 4, respectively. I only want to exclude lines with G and C in columns 3 and 4, respectively.

I prefer to use awk for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way:

```
awk '!($3=="G" && $4=="C")' file
```

Trying to print the inverse of G & C combination